# Solution verification: Find all possible $x$ that satisfy $5x\equiv 1\;\;(mod\;\;6)$.

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Can someone please verify/explain why this solution works? I just know how to do it but I want to know why it works!

$5x\equiv 1\;\;(mod\;\;6)$

$5x = 1 + 6y$

$5n = -4 + y \;\;(mod \;\;5)$

$y = 5n + 4$

$5x = 1 + 6(5n + 4) = 1 + 5(6n) + 24 = 25 + 5(6n)$

$x = 5 + 6n, \;\; n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: An easier to explain solution is that $5\cdot 5=25=6\cdot 4 + 1$ so $5^{-1}=5$ in $\Bbb Z_6^{\times}$.  This means $5x\equiv 1\pmod{6}\implies 5\times (5x)\equiv 5\times (1)\pmod{6}\implies x\equiv 5\pmod{6}$

Comment: `I just know how to do it but I want to know why it works!` Which step specifically are you unsure of, and why? The posted solution does in fact work, but it's a rather roundabout way to do it.

Comment: @dxiv Why can I write $5x = 1 + 6y$ for $5x\equiv 1\;\;(mod\;\;6)$?

Comment: @numericalorange Because $5x \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$ means that $5x-1$ is a multiple of $6$ which you can write as $5x-1=6y$.

Answer (score 2):

Solving $$5x\equiv 1\;\;(mod\;\;6)$$ means finding  all  $x\in (0,1,2,3,4,5)$ which satisfy $ 5x=6k+1.$

Upon checking those numbers, we find that $x=5$ is the only one satisfying the equation.

Therefore the answer is $x=6k+5.$

Answer (score 1):

$5x \equiv 1 \pmod 6$

So

$5x \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ AND $5x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

So

$x \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ AND $x \equiv -1 \pmod 3$

So

$x \equiv -1  \pmod 6 \equiv 5 \pmod 6$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative hint:

$$\,5x\color{red}{+x}\equiv 1\color{red}{+x} \iff 6\,x \equiv 1+x \iff 0 \equiv 1+x \iff x \equiv -1 \iff x \equiv 5 \pmod{6}\,$$